# Ruby on Rails chaning methods on ActiveRecord doesnt work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I got this code, and i get the "Missing method" when i try to use the second more elegant approach. I think the documentation at: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html is rather unhelpful or incomplete. Any ideas?

By the way, feel free to help write an even more "oneliner" elegant approach to this :)

```
  def index
@sortby = params[:sort_by]

# THIS WORKS

#if @sortby == nil
#  @movies = Movie.all
#else
#  @movies = Movie.order(@sortby)
#end

# THIS DOESNT. WHY? I THOUGHT METHOD CHAINING AND LAZYLOAD WOULD WORK.
@movies = Movie.all
@movies = @movies.order(@sortby) unless @sortby == nil
```

end

Comment: Your code is open to sql injection attack: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7771103/rails-3-activerecord-order-what-is-the-proper-sql-injection-work-around

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`all` loads records and returns array. Try to use [scoped](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/NamedScope/ClassMethods/scoped):

```
@movies = Movie.scoped
@movies = @movies.order(@sortby) unless @sortby.nil?
```

Comment: And if I'm not mistaken, this is changing in Rails 4

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in one line.

```
@movies = params[:sort_by].nil? ? Movie.all : Movie.order(params[:sort_by]).all
```

In your case you are getting error about 'undefined method order for Array' I suppose. ActiveRecord method .all returns array.