# How to refactor long where clauses?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I refactor this code? Is there a way to split the where clause, the includes and the order functions?

```
def self.product_search(query, console, genre, sort, order)
        if query
            #search(query)
            if !console.nil? && console != "all" && !genre.nil? && genre != "all"
                where("name_en ilike :q AND console_id = :c AND genre_id = :g OR ean ilike :q AND console_id = :c AND genre_id = :g", q: "%#{query}%", c: console, g: genre).includes(:genre, :console, :brand, :images).order("#{sort} #{order}")
            elsif !console.nil? && console != "all"
                where("name_en ilike :q AND console_id = :c OR ean ilike :q AND console_id = :c", q: "%#{query}%", c: console).includes(:genre, :console, :brand, :images).order("#{sort} #{order}")
                elsif !genre.nil? && genre != "all"
                where("name_en ilike :q AND genre_id = :g OR ean ilike :q AND genre_id = :g", q: "%#{query}%", g: genre).includes(:genre, :console, :brand, :images).order("#{sort} #{order}")
            else
                where("name_en ilike :q OR ean ilike :q", q: "%#{query}%").includes(:genre, :console, :brand, :images).order("#{sort} #{order}")
            end
        end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can build AREL expressions in pieces; they're only executed when they're iterated over or otherwise used.  For example, you could do something like this:

```
def self.product_search(query, console, genre, sort, order)
  if query
    clause = all # Start with all, filter down.
    if !console.nil? && console != "all" && !genre.nil? && genre != "all"
      clause = clause.where("name_en ilike :q AND console_id = :c AND genre_id = :g OR ean ilike :q AND console_id = :c AND genre_id = :g", q: "%#{query}%", c: console, g: genre)
    elsif !console.nil? && console != "all"
      clause = clause.where("name_en ilike :q AND console_id = :c OR ean ilike :q AND console_id = :c", q: "%#{query}%", c: console)
    elsif !genre.nil? && genre != "all"
      clause = clause.where("name_en ilike :q AND genre_id = :g OR ean ilike :q AND genre_id = :g", q: "%#{query}%", g: genre)
    else
      clause = clause.where("name_en ilike :q OR ean ilike :q", q: "%#{query}%")
    end
    clause.includes(:genre, :console, :brand, :images).order("#{sort} #{order}")
  end
end
```

You can keep chaining and assigning until you've built the entire search clause you want.  This could be optimized a bunch more, but I think this is sufficient to demonstrate the main point about chaining AREL expressions.

You can also ditch many of those `nil` checks if you reverse some of the logic and check for `console.nil?` and `genre.nil?` first, and then in the `else` clauses, just check for `genre == "all"`, for example.

It's also possible to define some of these as named scopes on your model (or see this blog post called [Named Scopes Are Dead](http://www.railway.at/2010/03/09/named-scopes-are-dead/) for a better way), to DRY-up some of the code and make it more readable.

My example above is still in need of a lot of work but I think you can assemble some nice code by following that pattern.

Answer (score 0):

this might be taking things to far for you, but i would move that code into another object

```
# code in Product model
def self.product_search(search_criteria, console, genre, sort, order)
  return nil unless search_criteria.present?
  ProductSearch.new(search_criteria, genre, sort, order).find
end

# new class to handle Product search
class ProductSearch
  def initialize(search_criteria, console, genre, sort, order)
    @search_criteria = search_criteria
    @console = console
    @genre = genre
    @sort = sort
    @order = order
  end

  attr_reader :search_criteria, :console, :genre, :sort, :order

  def core_query_for_product_search
    # WARNING: .order("#{sort} #{order}") is open to sql injection attacks
    self.includes(:genre, :console, :brand, :images)
      .order("#{sort} #{order}")
      .where("name_en ilike :q OR ean ilike :q", q: "%#{search_criteria}%")
  end

  def with_console?
    !console.nil? && console != "all"
  end

  def with_genre?
    !genre.nil? && genre != "all" # you might want genre.present? instead of !genre.nil?
  end

  def find
    query = core_query_for_product_search
    query = query.where("genre_id = :g", g: genre) if with_genre?
    query = query.where("console_id = :c", c: console) if with_console?

    query
  end
end
```

couple of things to note:

1) sql injection in the order clause, rails is good at protecting where clause but not order, see [rails 3 activerecord order - what is the proper sql injection work around?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7771103/rails-3-activerecord-order-what-is-the-proper-sql-injection-work-around)

2) This no longer create the exact same sql as your query, but I am guessing the result is the same, rails AREL where chaining will always do `AND xxxxx` adding `OR` properly can be more difficult, but in your example code it appeared that `OR ean ilike :q` is in every one of those queries and no parentheses are used, so i put i in the core, maybe you actually want parentheses and a different result, couldn't understand why `AND console_id = :c` shows up twice in some of those queries