# Is ActiveRecord's order method safe for inserting user-entered strings?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to do something like this in Rails:

```
People.order("#{params[:sort]}, first_name, middle_name, last_name")
```

Is this safe? Or do I need to parse `params[:sort]` myself and make sure it's a list of valid columns beforehand? I don't mind getting a database error, but I can't have the possibility of SQL injection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

order is not safe by default

See:

- [rails 3 activerecord order - what is the proper sql injection work around?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7771103/rails-3-activerecord-order-what-is-the-proper-sql-injection-work-around)
- http://railscasts.com/episodes/228-sortable-table-columns

Comment: I wanted a comma separated list of attributes, but this answers my question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
if People.attribute_names.include?(params[:sort].to_s)
  People.order("#{params[:sort]}, first_name, middle_name, last_name")
end
```