# Sort in rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting, view

I am new to rails.In my rails application i want to sort content with respect to a dropdown list.

In my dropdown list i have several option like "name", "price".
Now if i press name from the list i want the content to be sorted by name of the content.see the picture:[image: when i select from the sort by dropdown then i want to sort the content according to selected option]

I have no idea how to do this in rails .

Please help me out.

Comment: check out [sort](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort) and [sort_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by)

Answer (score 2):

We can't suggest You anything specific unless You share Your controller code.
In most cases You just specify `order` clause to Your DB query.

For instance:

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    # assuming You passed order field in GET param: /products?order_by=name
    @products = Product.order(params[:order_by])
  end
end
```

**UPDATED**

You should be able to use it this [method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/Quoting.html#method-i-quote_column_name) for quoting. It's defined on Your connection object (`SomeModel.connection`)

```
irb(main):001:0> Movie.connection.quote_column_name("name")
=> "\"name\""
irb(main):004:0> Movie.connection.quote_column_name("name; DELETE FROM users;")
=> "\"name; DELETE FROM users;\""
```

Even better probably would be using only column names defined by You.

Comment: Beware, your example code is open to sql injection attacks, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7771103/rails-3-activerecord-order-what-is-the-proper-sql-injection-work-around - note rails will handle params passed to the where method, but not the order method

Comment: thanks for replying.My form code is :


    <%= form_for(@category, :url => sort_item_category_path, method: 'GET', :class=> " form-inline pull-left") do |f| %>
                  Sort By :
                  <select class="span2" id ="sort">
                    <option>Default</option>
                    <option>Name</option>
                    <option>Pirce</option>
                    <option>Rating </option>
                    <option>Color</option>
                  </select>
      end 
.i wanna know how to send the params[:order_by] to controller @edgarsJejabsons

Comment: Agree it should be escaped.

Comment: user1463066, add all code blocks to the question, Your comment is barely readable.