# How to make default_scope in Rails model dynamic?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

In one of my Rails models I have this:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user

  default_scope order("number ASC")

end
```

Now the problem is that I want each `user` to be able to set his or her `default_scope` individually. For example, a user A might want `default_scope order("date ASC")`, another one might want `default_scope order("number DESC")`.

In my `User` table I even have columns to store these values: `order_column` and `order_direction`.

But how can I make the `default_scope` in the model dynamic?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @screenmutt said, default scopes are not meant to be data-driven, they are meant to be model driven. Since this scope is going to change according to each user's data I'd use a regular scope for this.

@fmendez answer is pretty good but it uses default scope which I just explained why it is not recommended using this method.

This is what I'd do in your case:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :user_order, lambda { order("#{current_user.order_column} #{current_user.order_direction}")}
end
```

Also a very important thing to notice here is **SQL injection**: Since you are embedding `current_user.order_column` and `current_user.order_direction` inside your query, you **MUST** ensure that the user can only feed these columns into the database with valid data. Otherwise, users will be able to craft unwanted SQL queries.

Comment: +1 for sql injection warning - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7771103/rails-3-activerecord-order-what-is-the-proper-sql-injection-work-around for more details

Answer (score 2):

You won't want to use `default_scope`. What you do what is regular `scope`.

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :created_before, ->(time) { where("created_at < ?", time) }
end
```

[Scope | Ruby on Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes)

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
def self.default_scope
   order("#{current_user.order_column} #{current_user.order_direction}")
end
```

This should dynamically pick the values stored in the current_user's `order_column` and `order_direction` columns.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a class method with whatever logic you require and set your default scope to that. A class method is identical to a named scope when it returns a relation,eg by returning the result of a method like order.

For example:

```
def self.user_ordering
    # user ording logic here
end

default_scope :user_ordering
```

You may want to add a current_user and current_user= class methods to your User model which maintains the request user in a thread local variable. You would typically set the current user on your User model from your application controller. This makes current_user available to all your models for logic such as your sorting order and does it in a thread safe manner.