# Sorting an existing @products array in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm pretty new to working with Ruby and Rails and I'm hoping someone could point me in the right direction for solving a problem. Currently on my site I have a list of products that has been sorted by category, or by a status ("onsale", etc).

I'd like to sort the existing results by price and name, in ascending and descending order without having to write more queries to the DB. I'd like to click on a link (or maybe a button) and have the current @products variable sorted.

I found part of the solution here: [Re sorting active records in rails without re querying the database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22049725/re-sorting-active-records-in-rails-without-re-querying-the-database)

Specifically this:
    @products = @products.sort_by {|product| product.name} # Ruby Sorting

But what I'm not sure how to do is pass the existing @products array to a "sorting" controller and then "refresh" the page with the sorted results.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the database sort for you!

`Product.order(name: :asc, status: :desc)`

Check out the guide here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#ordering for more information

Comment: Thanks! If this is the best way to go, then I'll write some more queries.